# How can I include characters with my row delimiter of line feed? Java / Talend

Tags: java, delimiter, talend, carriage-return, linefeed

I have data that contains carriage returns. For that reason, I need a more complex row delimiter than just `/n`

The delimiter I would like to use is `|~/n`. I have tried that, `|~` +  `/n`, and `|~/n`. None have worked! Can someone suggest a syntax for this in `Talend`? I am using the `File Delimited` metadata.

Thank you!

Comment: How about using something different, like an ASCII control character? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: if i use tFileInputdelimited component to read the file and use Row Separator as "|~\n" in the Basic settings option, it works... I was able to read data with multiple line feeds in a row and |~\n as the row delimiter it was able to identify the different rows too.

Comment: Does your data with the carriage returns actually use `|~/n`? It might be good if you can show a screenshot of the text file with CR and LF shown using something like Notepad++